# /lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu line 80 /etc/default/rcs: no such file

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, fsck, recovery-mode

I am new to ubuntu/linux.
I have checked similar questions but it doesn't answer my question. In grub when i select network(wired) or fsck. i get the error message. /lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu line 80 /etc/default/rcs: no such file. I have checked there is no "rcs" file.  How would i go about fixing this?

My system is oldish custom pc.

Super thanks in advance.